# How do I sum 4 binary numbers?

Tags: arithmetic

I know how to do the simple binary addition, where there are only 2 binary numbers to be summed, but now I am dealing with 4 binary numbers:

```
 1 1 0 1
 1 1 0 0
   1 1 1
+  1 0 1
--------
```

How do I sum these numbers?

Comment: Addition is associative.

Comment: Add the first two, You'll end with one number. Then continue the cycle. If any doubts, please contact one of your middle school or junior school friends.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you know how to add 2 binary numbers, here's what you do. First add the first two numbers to get a number x. Then, add the second two numbers to get a number y. Finally, add together x and y.

Maybe this is clearest using parentheses:

1101 + 1100 + 111 + 101 = (1101 + 1100) + (111 + 101)